# How to get ajax get request to work to 'print' data from json file?

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

I'm making a 2-player game called shut the box, which involves 2 sets of 9 tiles (1 set per player). Each player takes a turn to roll the dice and can then choose which tiles to close as long as it is the same as the sum of the dice. Once the sum of the dice is higher than the sum of tiles, the player can't play anymore and the player with the lowest sum of open tiles is the winner.

[Preview of game layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWW2T.png)

The important detail of the game is to make it playable by 2 players on 2 separate devices. So the game must be updated without the page being loaded, so using AJAX. This is the part that is not working.

So for the game in using PHP to make the gamepage and home page and templates like header etc. JavaScript, mainly jQuery is used for the mechanics of the game, Ajax is used for fetching the game information (in order to test AJAX, for now it only retrieves `diceValue` and `currentPlayer`) and printing it on the page.

Right now I am able to post the `diceValue` and `currentPlayer` on gameState.json, so function rollDice() works including the Ajax POST request. The data in gameState.json looks like this:

`{"diceValue":"3","currentPlayer":"Player 1"}`

The problem currently is that I am not able to retrieve this data using the Ajax GET request in function `updateGameState`.

Part of `game.js`:

```
function rollDice() {
    var tileButtons = $(".player-board button");
    var currentPlayer = "Player 1";
    let diceResult = $("#diceResult");
    diceValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 2;
    diceResult.text("Dice result: " + diceValue);
    console.log("diceValue:", diceValue);
    
    // Posts diceValue and currentPlayer to gameState.json to retrieve later
    $.ajax({
        url: "scripts/add_dicevalue_currentplayer.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            diceValue: diceValue,
            currentPlayer: currentPlayer},
        dataType: "text",
        success: function () {
            console.log("gelukt");
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.error("nee", error);
        }
    });
    checkEndGame(tileButtons, diceValue, currentPlayer)
    toggleButtons();
}

function updateGameState() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "scripts/update_game_state.php",
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(gameState) {
            var diceValue = gameState.diceValue;
            var currentPlayer = gameState.currentPlayer;

            // Check if it works
            console.log("diceValue:", diceValue);
            console.log("currentPlayer:", currentPlayer);

            $("#diceValue").text("Dice result: " + diceValue);
            $("#currentPlayer").text("Current player: " + currentPlayer);
            console.log("wel gelukt");
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.error("niet gelukt", error);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    // when the button to roll is clicked, roll the dice
    let rollButton = $("#rollButton");
    rollButton.on("click", rollDice);

    // retrieve diceValue and currentPlayer
    updateGameState();

    });
}
```

`add_dicevalue_currentplayer` file:

```
<?php
//posts the diceValue and currentPlayer on gameState.json
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
    if (isset($_POST['diceValue']) && isset($_POST['currentPlayer'])) {
        $diceValue = $_POST['diceValue'];
        $currentPlayer = $_POST['currentPlayer'];

        // create array to store needed values
        $gameState = [
            'diceValue' => $diceValue,
            'currentPlayer' => $currentPlayer
        ];

        // encode the array to json and put the data in gameState.json
        $jsonData = json_encode($gameState);
        file_put_contents('../data/gameState.json', $jsonData);
    } else {
        echo 'values are missing';
    }
} else {
    echo 'NOpe';
}
```

`update_game_state.php`:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "GET") {
    if (isset($_GET['diceValue']) && isset($_GET['currentPlayer'])) {
        $diceValue = $_GET['diceValue'];
        $currentPlayer = $_GET['currentPlayer'];

        $jsonData = file_get_contents('../data/gameState.json');
        $gameState = json_decode($jsonData, true);

        $gameState['diceValue'] = $diceValue;
        $gameState['currentPlayer'] = $currentPlayer;

        $jsonData = json_encode($gameState);
        file_put_contents('../data/gameState.json', $jsonData);


        // Send the updated game state as the response
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo $jsonData;
    } else {
        echo 'geen dicevalue en currentplayer';
    }
} else {
    echo 'nope';
}
```

The code above is how I've tried to retrieve the data using the GET request. At the moment I get the error 'geen dicevalue en current player' which shows in  `update_game_state.php`:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "GET") {
    if (isset($_GET['diceValue']) && isset($_GET['currentPlayer'])) {
        $diceValue = $_GET['diceValue'];
        $currentPlayer = $_GET['currentPlayer'];

        $jsonData = file_get_contents('../data/gameState.json');
        $gameState = json_decode($jsonData, true);

        $gameState['diceValue'] = $diceValue;
        $gameState['currentPlayer'] = $currentPlayer;

        $jsonData = json_encode($gameState);
        file_put_contents('../data/gameState.json', $jsonData);


        // Send the updated game state as the response
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo $jsonData;
    } else {
        echo 'geen dicevalue en currentplayer';
    }
} else {
    echo 'nope';
}
```

It seems that the `diceValue` and `currentPlayer` are not being read off of the gameState.json file, but I don't know how to fix this issue.

Did I write the function `updateGameState` wrong or is it in the wrong spot or is the PHP file that's supposed to handle the GET request wrong? I am a bit lost at the moment and don't know how I can fix it.

If there is additional information needed in order to understand this problem, feel free to ask!

Comment: In `update_game_state.php`, you only respond with JSON if the `diceValue` and `currentPlayer` URL query parameters are present. Your AJAX request sends neither of them. Responding with `'geen dicevalue en currentplayer'` is **not** JSON so the client-side parsing fails.

Comment: Looks like you simply forgot to include the `data:` parameter in `updateGameState()`.

Comment: How do you keep both players from overwriting the `gameState.json` file at the same time?

Comment: @Philisonstrike How can I solve this issue?

Comment: @Barmar I now added the data parameter  but it's still not running the way it's supposed to, any tips?

Comment: BTW, in general you should not use `GET` for updates, you should use `POST`. `GET` responses are cached by default (you can add `cache: false` to prevent this), so multiple requests with the same values will not send to the server.

Comment: Please update the question to show how you added the parameters.